# How can I modify my `ls` command?

Tags: command-line

When I type `ls`, i get the normal list, or when I type `ls -la` I get a details version with everything...

But I hate the layout of `ls`, it's just unintuitive for most of my use.

Is there some way I can modify (without changing the sorcecode of `ls`, bash scripts are okay however) `ls` so it's display instead of

```
-rwxr-xr-x 13 user group 123546 2011-01-01 11:11 filename0
-rwxr-xr-x 13 user group 123546 2011-01-01 11:11 filename1
-rwxr-xr-x 13 user group 123546 2011-01-01 11:11 filename2
drwx------ 13 user group 123546 2011-01-01 11:11 directory0
-rwxr-xr-x 13 user group 123546 2011-01-01 11:11 filename3
drwx------ 13 user group 123546 2011-01-01 11:11 directory1
```

I can get a list more like:

```
DIRS
directory0 1293880260 700 user:group
directory1 1293880260 700 user:group

FILES
filename0 1293880260 751 user:group
filename1 1293880260 755 user:group
filename2 1293880260 777 user:group
filename3 1293880260 705 user:group
```

Or some other variation.

Meanwhile, preserving ability to use flags and other options.

Answer (score 15):

You could write a bash script called `~/bin/ls` that should override `/bin/ls`. remember to run `chmod +x ~/bin/ls`.

I've just written this which seems to do most of what you want to accomplish (including passing along extra arguments)

```
#!/bin/bash

DIRS="`/bin/ls --color=auto -l $@ | grep ^d`"
FILES="`/bin/ls --color=auto -l $@ | grep ^\-`"

if [ "$DIRS" ]
then
    echo "DIRECTORIES"
    echo -e "$DIRS\

"
fi

if [ "$FILES" ]
then
    echo "FILES"
    echo "$FILES\

"
fi
```

Somebody might want to tidy that up a little or improve the output formatting, but there you go. Yours to do whatever you like with.

And here's some genuine sample output:

```
ls
DIRECTORIES
drwxr-xr-x 4 oli oli     4096 2010-12-16 15:40 markitup
drwxr-xr-x 7 oli oli     4096 2011-01-16 16:58 media
drwxr-xr-x 3 oli oli     4096 2010-12-16 15:41 post
drwxr-xr-x 9 oli oli     4096 2010-09-16 05:23 templates

FILES
-rw-r--r-- 1 oli oli  5361664 2010-09-06 16:32 db.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 oli oli        0 2008-12-11 09:22 __init__.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 oli oli      542 2008-12-11 09:22 manage.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 oli oli       13 2010-03-23 18:14 settingsdev.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 oli oli     2642 2010-12-16 15:40 settings.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 oli oli     1818 2010-12-16 15:40 urls.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 oli oli      432 2010-06-22 20:54 views.py
```

And with arguments:

```
ls -a
DIRECTORIES
drwxr-xr-x  8 oli oli     4096 2011-01-12 00:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 oli oli     4096 2011-04-13 17:24 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 oli oli     4096 2010-02-03 13:50 .bzr
drwxr-xr-x  4 oli oli     4096 2010-12-16 15:40 markitup
drwxr-xr-x  7 oli oli     4096 2011-01-16 16:58 media
drwxr-xr-x  3 oli oli     4096 2010-12-16 15:41 post
drwxr-xr-x  9 oli oli     4096 2010-09-16 05:23 templates

FILES
-rw-r--r--  1 oli oli       65 2010-03-27 07:58 .bzrignore
-rw-r--r--  1 oli oli  5361664 2010-09-06 16:32 db.db
-rw-r--r--  1 oli oli        0 2008-12-11 09:22 __init__.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 oli oli      542 2008-12-11 09:22 manage.py
-rw-r--r--  1 oli oli       13 2010-03-23 18:14 settingsdev.py
-rw-r--r--  1 oli oli     2642 2010-12-16 15:40 settings.py
-rw-r--r--  1 oli oli     1818 2010-12-16 15:40 urls.py
-rw-r--r--  1 oli oli      432 2010-06-22 20:54 views.py
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's my quick jab at it.

```
$ function lss { ls -l --group-directories-first --time-style +%s $@ | grep -v '^total' | awk 'BEGIN {print("DIRS")} {if (f!=1 && $1 ~ /^-/) {print "\nFILES"; f=1}; printf("%s\t%s %s %s:%s\n", $7, $6, $1, $3, $4);}'; }
$ alias ls='lss'
$ ls
DIRS
directory0  1305901476 drwxr-xr-x ak:ak
directory1  1305901476 drwxr-xr-x ak:ak

FILES
filename0   1305901484 -rw-r--r-- ak:ak
filename1   1305901484 -rw-r--r-- ak:ak
filename2   1305901484 -rw-r--r-- ak:ak
filename3   1305901484 -rw-r--r-- ak:ak
```

The benefit of this approach is that it does not require multiple directory traversals and prints the output as it is ready. Try running this after `touch filename{0..10000}` as a test.

Drop the `function` and `alias` lines into `~/.bashrc` to make it permanent.

Benchmarking from Oli:

```
oli@bert:~/Desktop$ mkdir test
oli@bert:~/Desktop$ cd test
oli@bert:~/Desktop/test$ mkdir dir{0..100000}
oli@bert:~/Desktop/test$ touch filename{0..100000}

oli@bert:~/Desktop/test$ time /bin/ls>/dev/null

real    0m0.975s
user    0m0.860s
sys         0m0.110s

oli@bert:~/Desktop/test$ time ls --group-directories-first -l >/dev/null

real    0m1.810s
user    0m1.210s
sys         0m0.580s


oli@bert:~/Desktop/test$ time lss>/dev/null  # ændrük's method

real    0m2.035s
user    0m1.810s
sys         0m0.780s

oli@bert:~/Desktop/test$ time ~/bin/ls>/dev/null  # Oli's method

real    0m5.496s
user    0m4.290s
sys         0m1.460s
```

Comment: Added some benchmarking to your post (as you mentioned it). Yeah over 100,000 directories and 100,000 files, yours takes less than half the time. But `ls` on its own is still a lot faster. Either way, this is a edge case. Most people never have such huge directory listings. For normal people, there's little observable difference. Nice `awk`ing though. +1

Answer (score 4):

`ls -la | grep "^d" && ls -la | grep "^-" && ls -la | grep "^l"`

Shows... directories, normal files, links in that order.

Make it an alias and you are set to go.

Found another method:

`ls -l --color -h --group-directories-first`

This one does directories first and colors the filenames.

In `~/.bashrc` you can create an alias to this command like so:

`alias ls1='ls -la | grep "^d" && ls -la | grep "^-" && ls -la | grep "^l"`

Sample output:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 96 2011-05-20 13:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 xxxx uuuu 96 2010-03-05 12:34 ..
drwx------  2 xxxx uuuu 96 2009-02-13 14:31 .ssh
drwxrwxr-x  2 xxxx uuuu 96 2009-12-03 13:49 .xxx
drwxrwxr-x  5 xxxx uuuu  96 2010-12-06 15:51 xxxxxx
-rw-------  1 xxxx uuuu  05 2011-05-20 14:12 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 xxxx uuuu  20 2009-02-12 09:33 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 xxxx uuuu 29 2009-03-06 11:47 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--  1 xxxx uuuu 80 2011-05-20 13:42 fff
-rw-rw-r--  1 xxxx uuuu 03 2011-05-18 10:21 dffff
```

or for the second one: `alias ls2=ls -l --color -h --group-directories-first`

Sample output:

```
drwxrwxr-x 5 xxxx uuuu 4.0K 2010-12-06 15:51 ddddd
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxx uuuu 339M 2011-05-20 13:42 sssss
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxxx uuuu 4.6M 2011-05-18 10:21 dxsssss
-rwxrwxr-x 1 xxxx uuuu   68 2011-02-22 15:55 5555
-rwxr--r-- 1 xxxx uuuu  20K 2010-12-06 16:11 ffff
```

ddddd will be in another color. add `-a` to also include hidden files.

and you created a command ls1 and ls2 to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Extending the alias settings in .bashrc is my prefered way of getting more convenient 'ls' commands. I like especially the 'lf' (requires installation of 'tree').

```
# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias lf='tree -d -L 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

`ls` doesn't support much output customization.

Use

```
 ls --group-directories-first -l
```

to just get the dirs first.

Have a look at [limo](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/limo.1.html) (not installed by default) for an alternative to ls that supports more output customization (but doesn't support all the options of `ls`)

Answer (score 1):

One of the most powerful tools in Unix systems is the `find` command. We can use it to emulate `ls` output with `-ls` flag and search by file type with `-type` flag. Thus, what you see bellow is the exactly the same command , but with `find` searching for two different types. `printf` statements only tell you want it's listing first.

```
printf "****DIRS****\n"; find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -ls; echo "****FILES****"; find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -ls
```

Here is sample output:

```
CURRENT DIR:[/home/xieerqi/bin]
$ printf "****DIRS****"; find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -ls; echo "****FILES****"; find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -ls                                 
****DIRS****
5795516    4 drwxrwxr-x   8 xieerqi  xieerqi      4096 Aug 19 16:25 .
5795514    4 drwxrwxr-x   2 xieerqi  xieerqi      4096 Aug 19 15:27 ./c
5795511    4 drwxrwxr-x   2 xieerqi  xieerqi      4096 Aug 19 15:27 ./python
5795153    4 drwxrwxr-x   2 xieerqi  xieerqi      4096 Aug 19 15:41 ./perl
5795532    4 drwxrwxr-x   2 xieerqi  xieerqi      4096 Aug 19 15:27 ./random
5795531    4 drwxrwxr-x   2 xieerqi  xieerqi      4096 Aug 19 15:27 ./sh
5795141    4 drwxrwxr-x   2 xieerqi  xieerqi      4096 Aug 19 15:27 ./cs2
****FILES****
5795538    4 -rw-rw-r--   1 xieerqi  xieerqi       178 Aug 19 16:25 ./somefile.txt
5795539    4 -rw-rw-r--   1 xieerqi  xieerqi       219 Aug 19 16:26 ./somefile2.txt
```

Notice, that `find` lists *all*, the files, including the hidden files with the leading dot , for instance `.bashrc`.

Now, to make this command easier to access, create an alias to that  in your `.bashrc`. I've made mine like so

```
alias ls2='printf "****DIRS****\n"; find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -ls; echo "****FILES****"; find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -ls '
```

Source bashrc with `. .bashrc` or exit and enter terminal. Your alias is now ready for use any time you want it.

Comment: Most powerful tool? Indeed. :)

Answer (score 0):

My latest `ls` mod in `~/bin` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
ACCOUNT_ID=$UID
#
#SET ACCOUNT_NAME
ACCOUNT_NAME=$( cat /etc/passwd | grep $ACCOUNT_ID | cut -d: -f1 );

ls -l -F --color -h --group-directories-first $1 |\
    sed "s/$ACCOUNT_NAME/\$USER/g" | ack --passthru --color \\\$USER ;
```

P.S. Had to name it `~/bin/myls` or it'll hang in loop that never reaches the system's `ls`.

Sample Output:

```
$ sudo mkdir -vp /temp/Nother_DIR | tee -a /tmp/record
mkdir: created directory `/temp'
mkdir: created directory `/temp/Nother_DIR'
$ sudo chown -vR $USER:$USER /temp | f | tee -a /tmp/record
changed ownership of `/temp/Nother_DIR' to $USER:$USER
changed ownership of `/temp' to $USER:$USER
$ cd /temp
$ touch a b c d
$ ln -sv d e | tee -a /tmp/record
`e' -> `d'
$ ln -sv e f | tee -a /tmp/record
`f' -> `e'
$ myls | tee -a /tmp/record
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 $USER $USER 4.0K Sep 19 00:46 Nother_DIR
-rw-r--r-- 1 $USER $USER    0 Sep 19 00:46 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 $USER $USER    0 Sep 19 00:46 b
-rw-r--r-- 1 $USER $USER    0 Sep 19 00:46 c
-rw-r--r-- 1 $USER $USER    0 Sep 19 00:46 d
lrwxrwxrwx 1 $USER $USER    1 Sep 19 00:46 e -> d
lrwxrwxrwx 1 $USER $USER    1 Sep 19 00:46 f -> e
```

Answer (score -1):

My latest ls mod in ~/bin is:

```
#!/bin/bash
ACCOUNT_ID=$UID
# 
#SET ACCOUNT_NAME
ACCOUNT_NAME=$( cat /etc/passwd | grep $ACCOUNT_ID | cut -d: -f1 );  

ls -l -F --color -h --group-directories-first $1 |\  
    sed "s/$ACCOUNT_NAME/\$USER/g" | ack --passthru --color \\\$USER ;
```

Sorry about post's format. Tried to make usable via copy/paste, but maybe no go. Cheers!
P.S. Had to name it ~/bin/myls or it'll hang in loop that never reaches the system's ls.

Comment: `ACCOUNT_NAME="$(getent passwd $UID | cut -d: -f1)"` and `/bin/ls -l -F ...`